# How to add and extend a new row in Python list?

Tags: python, arrays

I have to reduce the density of an array, by using a for loop that traverses by steps of 100 and copy the value of my original array into a new array:

soundDataHere is a `[7][22000]` dim array, and I want cleanSoundData to be a `[7][220]` dim array

```
def reduceDensity(soundDataHere):
    for i in range(numberOfFiles):
        for j in range(0, soundDataHere[i].size-1, 100):
            cleanSoundData.extend(soundDataHere[i][j])
```

I keep dont know how to use the append and extend function in a foor loop to recreate a new less dense array.

example: `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]` with a `step = 2` 
should return `[[1,3,5],[6,8,10]]` in my new cleanSoundData array

but is only extending it like `[1,3,5,6,8,10]`

Comment: Is using the numpy module an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using Numpy and your example:

```
import numpy as np

l = [1,3,5,6,8,10]
l2 = np.reshape(l,[2,-1])

>>> l2
array([[ 1,  3,  5],[ 6,  8, 10]])
```

It looks like you're working with sound data so I would highly recommend using the numpy module as vectorizing array operations will be far faster than using a for loop with Python objects (up to 100x faster in some cases).

The Numpy module was designed specifically for these type of use cases so I would encourage you to learn how to use it.

Comment: Yes okay I will consider using numpy, however its tough to use reshape all the time because all sound samples do not have the same size. But thanks I can probably work around this problem with a little bit more code

Comment: np.reshape(l,[2,-1]) -- the -1 here means to auto-adjust to the size so as long as the array is even sized, it will work. If you could give more info on the structure of the data, I might be able to give you some better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try creating two different temporary list objects where you 'extend' the required elements into each one of them(that is the right and the left sublist) just after the for loop. Then 'append' those two lists instead of extending in the cleanSoundData.

Comment: thats possible but more memory hungry and slower, if theres another better method to do it that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array `soundData` is a `7 X 22000` holds your data. So creating a new array `cleanSoundData` of size `7 x 220` can be done as follows. Even it is more generalized whether its `2 x 1000` or `1000 x 50000`.

```
cleanSoundData = []
for i in range(len(soundData)):
    cleanSoundData.append([]) # adding new row
    for j in range(0, len(soundData[i]), 100):
        cleanSoundData[i].append(soundData[i][j]) # adding data to the row
```

Hope this will work for you.